# Will shopkeepers infected by rot die?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I accidentally sold a Tenebrium infused weapon to a shopkeeper and now he has rot and is taking 1 rot damage every turn.  Does this mean that he will eventually die?  In this case he's actually an undead shopkeeper so I have no clue what will happen.

Comment: Did you finally found out what will happen, or are you still requiring an answer? If you still want an answer, I can try to reproduce it tonight, although I'm not sure I will be able to try that on an undead shopkeeper

Comment: @CaffeinatedCake I'm still curious what would happen, I ended up reloading before I sold the item just be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it was a long run, but I can confirm it: it goes until they have 1 HP left.

[image: Let's rot]
[image: Almost there]
[image: Yep, it's confirmed]

Comment: ty for testing!

Comment: now I wonder if this would work on any immaculates as a sneaky way of prepping them for death

Comment: Well, rejoice because I tried it and I can also confirm that it's working. I didn't had the patience to wait until they had 1 HP, but when the fight began, the two merchants orcs that I contaminated had only half of their life. If you can contaminate a maximum of characters before doing all the quests leading to the extermination of the illuminates, it should make everything easy like a pie.

Answer (score 0):

It goes until they have 1 life left.

Comment: Hi groby73, can you post a screenshot or something to support your answer?  thanks